# What are the visualisations used in this Power BI promo material?

Tags: powerbi

Looking at the Power BI examples within the Microsoft Store, you can see several non-standard visualisations but no indication on what they are actually called.  I have found the Dial Guage but can't seem to find anything else on the others.

Is anyone aware of what these visualisations are called?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one at the bottom left is the "Dial Gauge".

The ones on the top left and right are the same I guess. This is the "Synoptic Panel by OKViz". Very powerfull one.

For the last one on the bottom right, I would say "Story-Teller" but not sure about this one.

But still, they are all custom visuals. Hope it will help.

Comment: Synoptic Panel was my first thought, though for the visualisation in the top right, how is the icon displayed on top of the fill colour?

Comment: No idea about that, maybe it is the "Infographic Designer" but not sure ;)